# Getting accurate roots of quadratic equation

Tags: java, performance

This is the code that I have thus far.  The goal of the project is to have the user enter any integers for `a`, `b`, `c` for the `ax^2+bx+c` equation.  For some reason I am not getting the correct roots for any numbers that are input into the program.  Can anyone point out my wrong doings?

```
import java.util.*;


public class Quad_Form {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double discrim = 0;
    double d = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter value for 'a'");
    String str_a = sc.nextLine();
    a = Integer.parseInt(str_a);

    System.out.println("Enter value for 'b'");
    String str_b = sc.nextLine();
    b = Integer.parseInt(str_b);

    System.out.println("Enter value for 'c'");
    String str_c = sc.nextLine();
    c = Integer.parseInt(str_c);

    double x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
    discrim = (Math.pow(b, 2.0)) - (4 * a * c);
    d = Math.sqrt(discrim);

    if(discrim == 0){
        x1 = (-b + d) / (2* a);
        String root_1 = Double.toString(x1);
        System.out.println("There is one root at: " + root_1);
        }

    else {
        if (discrim > 0)
        x1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a);
        String root_1 = Double.toString(x1);
        String root_2 = Double.toString(x2);
        System.out.println("There are two real roots at:"  + root_1 + "and"  + root_2);
        }

    if (discrim < 0){

        x1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a);
        String root_1 = Double.toString(x1);
        String root_2 = Double.toString(x2);
        System.out.println("There are two imaginary roots at:" + root_1 + "and" + root_2);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you use the `pow()` function to compute a square?  `(Math.pow(b, 2.0)) - (4 * a * c)`   Why not simply multiply by itself?  `b * b - (4 * a * c)`   This is less likely to cause trouble with negative values of `b` and also avoid decreased precision caused by `pow()`.

Answer (score 2):

@Smit is right about one of the issues, but there's a second one as well.

`Math.sqrt(discrim)` won't work when `discrim` is negative.  You should be taking `Math.sqrt(Math.abs(discrim))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are double and you are parsing them as Integer. So this could be one of problem.

Use

```
 Double.parseDouble();
```

Another problem is you can not make square root of negative numbers. This will result in `NaN`. For that use following, but you should handle that properly to get exact result.

```
  Math.sqrt(Math.abs());
```

Moreover you should use following formula for getting roots

[image: the roots are given by the quadratic formula[]

Taken from Wikipedia [Quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)

[Class Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

[Class Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(double))

Comment: Haha, small mistake that I managed to look over while changing code.  But I still do not get the right answer. If I were to input 1 for a, 5 for b, and 6 for c; I should get the roots -2 and -3. Instead I get 0.5 and 0.5

Comment: @KGidorahh as other answer saying you can not make square root of negative number. You have to handle that situation.

Comment: @KGidorahh I updated the answer. I hope this will solve your misery.